# send event to local datadog agent via shell

Tags: shell, datadog

I'm trying to send events to my local datadog agent by shell through DataStatsD port. The message is sent without errors but doesn't reach the dashboard.

I use datadog agent in version 6.9 and use datadog documentation:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/datagram_shell/#send-metrics-and-events-using-dogstatsd-and-the-shell

When I try to send metrics is work fine and I see the metrics in the datadog dashboard but when I send events it's doesn't show in the dashboard.

I also see that when I send event via shell and then check agent status the number of metrics packets go up but the number of events is still 0.

That's the command i run:

```
~$ title="Event from the shell"
~$ text="This was sent from Bash!"
~$ echo “_e{${#title},${#text}}:$title|$text|#shell,bash"  
     >/dev/udp/localhost/8125
```

**Edit** When I changed the following configuration properties it's work.
         The configuration I changed:
         1) dogstatsd_non_local_traffic: yes
         2) bind_host: localhost

Comment: maybe your first `{` and last `}` chars need to be escaped like `\{` and `\}` ?  And maybe you can share the output of "echo" without writing it to the dogstatsd socket?

Comment: actually i just ran these in my own bash, and the `!` in `text` was doing something weird. and then the `echo` needed a leading `"` character but seemed otherwise fine

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I remove the ! character and I have a typo in the echo line but I used “ and it stil dosen’t work. You have any idea why?

Comment: good find on the config changes!